# How can I profile the SELECT statements inside stored procedures when using SQL Server Profiler for Azure Data Studio on an Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, profiler

The SQL Server Profiler for Azure Data Studio shows stored procedures, when connected to an Azure SQL Database.

[image]

Is it possible to profile the SELECT statements inside the stored procedures?

Is the reason why I seem unable to do it because there is only one (limited) template provided with the profiler when accessing Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 4):

The SQL Server Profiler GUI within Azure Data Studio is just a front-end for Extended Events. If you want to set up different data collection, such as sp_statement_completed to see individual statements within procedures, you just have to define an Extended Events session with that event and you're good to go. [Here are the basics to get that done](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). Instead of the SSMS GUI, use the "Corresponding T-SQL" section as the guide for creating your own session. You may also want to correlate the individual statements with the start & stop of the procedure itself, rpc_starting and rpc_completed. In that case, use Causality Tracking as I show it [here on my blog](https://www.scarydba.com/2020/01/13/causality-tracking-in-extended-events/). Then, you can [query the XML output](https://www.scarydba.com/2021/04/05/extended-events-embrace-the-xml/), or, [use another tool](https://www.scarydba.com/2021/03/29/extended-events-avoid-the-xml/) to consume the information (I do prefer DBATools for that approach).

That should give you everything you need.

Comment: Just a word of caution on this one, sp_statement_completed can be very intense depending on the workload you are running.  For example it captures all lines of SQL in a user-defined function, so if you're joining on one, you'll get all lines of SQL for every row (I think anyway).  So I would normally: filter by spid, stop and start the session for a specific query / workload, and don't run on prod.  Definitely don't leave running on prod overnight or over a long weekend when you've gone on holiday  ... ; )

Comment: Thanks @Grant Fritchey. Just starting simply with what you wrote and your links. In SSMS I ran `CREATE EVENT SESSION mysession ON DATABASE add event sqlserver.sp_statement_completed` - is this by itself supposed to add to the SQL Server Profiler GUI within Azure Data Studio, or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Thanks @wBob-MSFT - I will bear that in mind when I get this working! :)

Comment: Whoops. I just saw I need to do `ALTER EVENT SESSION mysession ON DATABASE STATE = START` as well. But I still I don't see the `sp_statement_completed` appearing in the Profiler.

Comment: And following from my comments above, one would need to select the profile called `mysession` from the profiler. Alternatively, one could do an `ALTER EVENT SESSION ADS_Standard_AZURE` to add the extra event to the existing default profile.

Comment: It's not going to appear in the ADS Profiler. The links in the last sentence show how to consume the data.

Comment: As to the events, again, I'd probably put in rpc_starting and completed along with causality tracking, all linked up above. As @wBob-MSFT says, this can be resource intensive, so, the other thing I'd suggest is to filter by object_id at the start to only look at the ones that are the most painful currently, not collect everything.

Comment: Also, total agreement with everything that @wBob-MSFT says.